# Python and Excel Formula

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, formula

Complete beginner here but have a specific need to try and make my life easier with automating Excel.
I have a weekly report that contains a lot of useless columns and using Python I can delete these and rename them, with the code below.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('TestExcel.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

ws.delete_cols(1,3)
ws.delete_cols(3,8)
ws.delete_cols(4,3)

ws.insert_cols(3,1)

ws['A1'].value = "Full Name"
ws['C1'].value = "Email Address"

ws['C2'].value = '=B2&"@testdomain.com"'

wb.save('TestExcelUpdated.xlsx')
```

This does the job but I would like the formula to continue from B2 downwards (since the top row are headings).

```
ws['C2'].value = '=B2&"@testdomain.com"'
```

Obviously, in Excel it is just a case of dragging the formula down to the end of the column but I'm at a loss to get this working in Python. I've seen similar questions asked but the answers are over my head.
Would really appreciate a dummies guide.
[Example of Excel report after Python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFHUn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to do this is by iterating over the rows in your worksheet.

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2): #min_row ensures you skip your header row
    row[2].value  = '=B' + str(row[0].row) + '&"@testdomain.com"'
```

`row[2].value` selects the third column due to zero based indexing. `row[0].row` gets the number corresponding to the current row

Comment: Brillant, thanks for your reply and detailed answer. Really helps to learn.
I've tried your code and although it looks like it should work, Excel doesn't seem to like it. The formula that ends up with Excel is =B2&@testdomain.com.
I've even tried 
`row[2].value  = '=B' + str(row[0].row) + "&" + "@testdomain.com"`
but that gives the same result.

Comment: Figured out the issue. Was missing a quotation mark or two. 
`row[2].value = '=B' + str(row[0].row) + '&"@jtltraining.ac.uk"'`

Comment: sorry, missed your original reply. I've update my answer to include your amendments. please mark as accepted if this solved your problem :)